# Dependent name resolution & namespace std / Standard Library

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, token-name-resolution

While answering [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16544974/420683) (better read [this "duplicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4447827/420683)), I came up with the following solution to dependent name resolution of an operator:

[temp.dep.res]/1:

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>
> - Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
> - Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context (14.6.4.1) and from the definition context.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// this operator should be called from inside `istream_iterator`
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, std::pair<int,int>& p)
{
    s >> p.first >> p.second;
    return s;
}

// include definition of `istream_iterator` only after declaring the operator
// -> temp.dep.res/1 bullet 1 applies??
#include <iterator>

#include <map>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("file.in");

    std::map<int, int> pp; 
    pp.insert( std::istream_iterator<std::pair<int, int>>{in},
               std::istream_iterator<std::pair<int, int>>{} );
}
```

But clang++ 3.2 and g++ 4.8 don't find this operator (name resolution).

<strike>Doesn't the inclusion of `<iterator>` define the "point of definition of the template" `istream_iterator`?</strike>

Edit: As [Andy Prowl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932150/andy-prowl) points out, this has nothing to do with the Standard Library, but rather with name lookup (can be proven by mimicking the Standard Library with multiple `operator>>`, at least one in the namespace of the fake `istream`).

---

Edit2: A workaround, using [basic.lookup.argdep]/2 bullet 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// can include <iterator> already here,
// as the definition of a class template member function
// is only instantiated when the function is called (or explicit instantiation)
// (make sure there are no relevant instantiations before the definition
//  of the operator>> below)
#include <iterator>

struct my_int
{
    int m;
    my_int() : m() {}
    my_int(int p) : m(p) {}
    operator int() const { return m; }
};

// this operator should be called from inside `istream_iterator`
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, std::pair<my_int,my_int>& p)
{
    s >> p.first.m >> p.second.m;
    return s;
}

#include <map>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("file.in");

    std::map<int, int> pp; 
    pp.insert( std::istream_iterator<std::pair<my_int, my_int>>{in},
               std::istream_iterator<std::pair<my_int, my_int>>{} );
}
```

Of course, you can also use your own `pair` type, as long as the workaround introduces an associated class in the namespace of the custom `operator>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the point where your call to `operator >>` is being made is somewhere inside the `std` namespace, and the namespace where the types of the arguments live is `std`.

Provided the compiler can find an `operator >>` in either the namespace where the call occurs or the namespace where the types of the arguments live (both are the `std` namespace in this case), no matter whether it is viable or not for overload resolution (which is performed *after* name lookup), it won't bother looking for more overloads of `operator >>` in parent namespaces.

Unfortunately, your `operator >>` lives in the global namespace and is, therefore, not found.

Comment: Could you provide a reference please? :) I'm eager to look that up in the Standard

Comment: Ok I got it :) [basic.lookup.unqual]/1; lookup in associated namespaces/argument-dependent lookup doesn't work here as both types are from `namespace std`.

Comment: AFAIK the only associated namespace is `namespace std`, and I don't want to inject the operator in there.

Comment: @DyP: Oh, OK, I misunderstood your sentence then